# How do i fix my stringcompare function so that it measure the entire string

Tags: c

```c
int comparestrings(char *x,char *y)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
         if (x[j]<y[j]) 
         {
              return 1;
         }
         else if(x[j]>y[j])
         {
              return 1;
         }
         else 
         {
              return 0;
         }
    }
}
```

both strings have a max length of 4 characters so measuring length isnt an issue. my problem is i need to figure out the order in which it needs to do stuff. it needs to compare bloodtypes of which there are only 8 possibilities. right now if the first character matches it will give a return value of 0 which will advance the program even if the following characters differ. so for instance if hte first value is A+ it will list out A+ A- AB+ AB- as well. where do i put the return values if i want this to measure the whole thing?

Comment: Scrap the `else { return 0;}` part and just put `return 0;` at the end of the function (outside the loop).

Comment: Isn't it supposed to return -1, 1 or 0?

Comment: Why are you writing your own function? What's wrong with the built-in `strcmp()`?

Comment: You can use strcmp(*x, *y) to compare between the two strings ,strcmp returns 0 if both strings are identical.